# Health Insurance for someone over 28 w/ dual US/German citizenship, moving to Paris from California for 4-8 months to study at the Sorbonne

Tags: france, health-insurance, dual-citizenship

I also have a NHS card from when I lived in London 2 years ago, but am moving from California. What kind of health insurance can I get? I don't seem to fit any of the normal boxes

Comment: Have you asked at the Sorbonne about the usual insurance arrangements for their foreign students?  Health insurance generally has more to do with your place of residence than your citizenship.

Comment: I have deleted my attempt to answer as I missed the 28 years age limit that @la-femme-cosmique raised.